Why is the result of this integration coming out as a list if the function being integrated just returns a numerical value?
I am trying to integrate over a Dirichlet distribution. Instead of using the built-in function, I defined it myself as:
a = 3;
k = 10;
beta = (Times @@ (Gamma[#]))/(Gamma[Total[#]]) &;
dirichlet = (Times @@ (#1^(#2 - 1)))/(beta[#2]) &;
GROUPS := ImplicitRegion[Total[{##}] == 1, Evaluate@Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, {##}}]] & @@ Array[x, a];
Integrate[dirichlet[group, k*Table[1/a, a]], group \[Element] GROUPS]

where a is the number of categories and k is a scaling constant. The GROUPS region contains the vectors of size a whose elements are between 0 and 1 and sum to 1. I'm pretty sure all of these definitions are right, but the result of Integrate is coming up as a list of a "random" number copied a times instead of 1 as I'd expect. I'm new to Mathematica and I'm using a lot of concepts and symbols for the first time here, so I probably messed up somewhere, but I can't figure out how. I included the values of a and k so it's easier to copy and run it, but they are parameters of the model.
Appreciate the help.
Note: I am not using the built-in distribution because it takes a vector of size a-1 as input and considers the last element as 1 minus the sum of the input inside its definition and I don't want that.

It's an order of evaluation issue, dirichlet[..] is being evaluated while group is a symbol, so you are actually doing the integral:
Inactive[Integrate][dirichlet[group, k*Table[1/a,a]], group ∈ GROUPS]


Inactive[Integrate][(362880 group^7)/Gamma[10/3]^3,
group ∈
ImplicitRegion[
x[1] + x[2] + x[3] == 1 && 0 <= x[1] <= 1 && 0 <= x[2] <= 1 &&
0 <= x[3] <= 1, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}]]

One possibility is to use an explicit list, e.g.:
Integrate[dirichlet[{g1, g2, g3}, k*Table[1/a, a]], {g1, g2, g3} ∈ GROUPS]


(16420096 π^2 Gamma[13/3])/(19683 Sqrt[3]
Gamma[-(4/3)] Gamma[10/3]^3 Gamma[20/3])


Does Integrate[f[x], x \[Element] GROUPS] ever work at all (for some function f and some implicit region GROUPS?

@MichaelE2 An example would be Integrate[x.x, x ∈ Disk[]]

Thanks, and Integrate[x . x, x ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]] works, too. Both are very fast. But if the region is ImplicitRegion[x^4 + y^4 <= 1, {x, y}], I get 0, even though Integrate[] can handle the iterated version, Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Surd[1 - x^4, 4], Surd[1 - x^4, 4]}].  (My answer, just posted, didn't work at first because of a mis-edit. That prompted my question.)

This implicit region integration failure has been filed as a bug (thank you @CarlWoll for pointing it out).

@DanielLichtblau Actually, it was Michael who noticed, I just brought it to your attention.

Thanks for the explanation. An explicit list wouldn't work in my case because its size is a parameter of the model, but thanks for the suggestion.

Another way to fix the evaluation issue is to block evaluation until the arguments of dirichlet (and optionally beta) are lists:
ClearAll[beta, dirichlet, GROUPS];
a = 3;
k = 10;
beta[x_List] := (Times @@ (Gamma[x]))/(Gamma[Total[x]]);
dirichlet[g_List, x_List] := (Times @@ (g^(x - 1)))/(beta[x]);
GROUPS[a_] := 
  ImplicitRegion[Total[{##}] == 1, 
     Evaluate@Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, {##}}]] & @@ Array[x, a];
Integrate[dirichlet[group, k*Table[1/a, a]], 
 group ∈ GROUPS[a]]


(*
(16420096 π^2 Gamma[13/3])/(19683 Sqrt[3]
  Gamma[-(4/3)] Gamma[10/3]^3 Gamma[20/3])
*)



This seems to be working, but for some reason the result of the integration is coming out as sqrt(a). Is my definition of the Dirichlet correct?

Actually, dividing by sqrt(a) works for low values of a, but not always. But everything else seems to be right, I don't know why the integration is not working properly...

These agree (with a = 3; k = 10): dirichlet[{x, y, 1 - x - y}, k*Table[1/a, a]]
and
PDF[DirichletDistribution[k*Table[1/a, a]], {x, y}]. I think the implicit-region integral is a surface integral. If you are trying to integrate the PDF to get 1, then you want an integral like Integrate[dirichlet[{x, y, 1 - x - y}, k*Table[1/a, a]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}] for a = 3. If so, dividing the implicit-region integral by Sqrt[a] should work. Possibly for high dimensions a the calculation gets too complicated for Mathematica to succeed.
